# js recursive function is called twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion

A have a recursive function, that every 5 seconds retrieves some data via jQuery.getJSON.

The problem is that the function is called twice.

First request is OK. How does the second request is appears, i cant understand. 
I use yii framework. "json" and "tweets" are controllers.

The requests:

```
GET /json/tweet/123456788 HTTP/1.1
GET /tweets/undefined HTTP/1.1
```

How i can get rid of useless request? Thanks.

```
function updateTweets()
{
var urlJson;

urlJson = "/json/latest";

if (tweetId)
    urlJson = "/json/tweet/" + tweetId;

$.getJSON(
    urlJson ,
    function(data){
        switch(data.status)
        {
            case 'success':
                html = processTweets(data.tweets);
                showTweets(html);
                setTimeout(updateTweets, 5000 /* 5 sec */);
                break;
            default:
                showMessage('Error!');
                break;
        }
        return false;
    })
.error(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        setTimeout(updateTweets, 12000 /* 12 sec */);
        return false;
    }
);
}
```

First call of "updateTweets":

```
var tweetId = 1234567;
$(function(){
      updateTweets();
 })',
```

Comment: by the way, when i delete "if(tweetId) .... " statement it works well...

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is outside this function. what's the logic for first updateTweets() call?

Comment: Where does the string `tweets` come from?

Comment: "tweets" is the current controller.

Comment: added first calling of "updateTweets" in bottom of the message.

Comment: Is you json/tweet/123456788 returning a 30x redirect? Who is calling the /tweets/undefined url?

Comment: "json/tweet/12345678" returns 200 HTTP status. double-requesting apears when i call $.getJSON -> function(data){ ... }